# How can I add database proxy in lambda via cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-proxy

I am using cloudformation to provision lambda and RDS on AWS. But I don't know how to add database proxy on lambda. Below screenshot is from lambda console:

[image]

Does cloudformation support adding this? I can't see it in lambda and db proxy template.

Comment: I have difficulties finding the answer. Have you found something?

Answer (score 3):

The exact configuration I use in CloudFormation template is:

```
MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Policies:
        - Version: '2012-10-17' 
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - rds-db:connect
              Resource:
                - <rds_proxy_arn>/*
```

where `<rds_proxy_arn>` is the ARN of the proxy but service is `rds-db` instead of `rds` and resource type is `dbuser` instead of `db-proxy`. For example, if your proxy's ARN is `arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:123456789012:db-proxy:prx-0123456789abcdef01` the whole line should be `arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:123456789012:db-proxy:prx-0123456789abcdef01/*`.

After deployed, we can see a new link is added in Database Proxies of the Console.

Answer (score 0):

As per the CloudFormation/Lambda [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html) there is no option to specify the DB Proxy for a Lambda.

I don't see an option to add an RDS proxy while [creating a Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateFunction.html) in the low level  HTTP API also. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

As per the following Github issue, it seems this is not required to connect lambda to RDS proxy. https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/750

You merely need to provide the new connection details to lambda (e.g. using env variables to make it work)

Answer (score 0):

After talking with AWS support, the screenshot in AWS console to add proxy on lambad is only to grant below IAM permission to lambda. That means it is an optional.

```
Allow: rds-db:connect
Allow: rds-db:*
```